# Issue when getting summary of OLSmodel

Tags: python

I have `femalesucide` array of `size (4,180)` and `HDIar` array of `size(4,180)`. I run the OLS regression but it gives error when I try to get model summary

```
femalesucide=np.array([femalesuiciderate2000,femalesuiciderate2005,femalesuiciderate2010,femalesuiciderate2015])
HDIar=np.array([HDIRank2000,HDIRank2005,HDIRank2010,HDIRank2015])
model4=sm.OLS(femalesucide,HDIar).fit()
prediction=model4.predict(HDIar)
print_model4=model4.summary()
print(print_model4)
```

I got following error:

> C:\Users\srija\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\stats\stattools.py:72: ValueWarning: omni_normtest is not valid with less than 8 observations; 4 samples were given.
>     "samples were given." % int(n), ValueWarning)
>   ValueError: shapes (4,180) and (4,180) not aligned: 180 (dim 1) != 4 (dim 0)

Answer (score 0):

Your dependent variable `femalesucide` is multivariate, i.e. two dimensional with several columns.

OLS only supports univariate dependent variables, that is `endog` should be one-dimensional. 
Because of the way the linear algebra works for the estimation, fit might work and estimate the `params`, but most other results do not work for multivariate dependent variables.

As alternative, you can either stack the dependent variables to have one univariate models and add the corresponding dummy variables and interaction terms, or use the `linearmodels` package and estimate a panel data model.

statsmodels does not yet have full support for models with multivariate dependent variables.